# Sumar dos campos de una tabla mysql en uno virtual

Tags: mysql

Cual sería la expresión correcta para sumar dos campos de una fila y que el resultado se mostrara de forma automática (STORED) cada vez que se cambian esos dos campos.

Los campos son vote_up y vote_down. Necesitaría la expresión que genere este resultado: (vote_up+vote_down)/vote_down y que esto se almacenara en story_likes.

¡Gracias!

Comment: Investiga sobre triggers

Comment: Considera una [*Columna Generada*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para crear un trigger que actualice el campo `story_likes` cada vez que se modifiquen los campos `vote_up` y `vote_down`, puedes probar este ejemplo:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_likes AFTER UPDATE ON tabla
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE tabla SET story_likes = (vote_up+vote_down)/vote_down WHERE id = NEW.id;
END
```